# Checking if the data already exsis in the wp database - custom plugin

Tags: database, duplicates

I'm trying to insert a user input to a custom table in wp and I don't want to have a duplicate entries. So my code to check that is:

```
    global $wpdb;
    $tablename=$wpdb->prefix."students"; //geting our table name with prefix
    $data=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT students_name, students_lastname FROM $tablename");
    foreach($data as $da){
        $da->students_name;
        $da->students_lastname; 
    }
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name=esc_attr($_POST['firstname']);
    $surname=esc_attr($_POST['lastname']);
    $email=sanitize_email($_POST['email']);

    //checking if the user already exsist so that we don't add it twice
    if (
    (is_email($email)) && 
    (($da->students_name != $name) && ($da->students_lastname != $surname)) 
    || (($da->students_name == $name) && ($da->students_lastname != $surname))
    || (($da->students_name != $name) && ($da->students_lastname == $surname)) 
    )
    {
    //assigning the new data to the table rows
        $newdata = array(
        'students_name'=>$name,
        'students_lastname'=>$surname,
        'students_email'=>$email,
        'students_date'=>current_time( 'mysql' ),
        );
        //inserting a record to the database
        $wpdb->insert(
        $tablename,
        $newdata
        );
    //displaying the success message when student is added
        ?>
        <div class="wrap">
            <div class="updated"><p>Student added!</p></div>
        </div>
    <?php
    }else {
        if(!is_email($email)){
            echo '<div class="error"><p>Invalid e-mail!</p></div>';
        }else{
        ?
    <div class="wrap">
            <div class="error"><p>Student exsist!</p></div> <!-- wp class error for error notices --->
        </div>
    <?php

        }
    }   
}
```

}

My problem is, when the user adds the data and if then adds the same data again immediately, the error message is shown and the user isn't added. Problem happens when user clicks to view the added records (another function) and then clicks to add the new student then the error message is not shown and the same user is entered twice or more. Any ideas?

Comment: You can get the result as an array and count it. If not 0 meaning the user already exists.

Comment: But in the database there can be the same name if it does not have the same last name and it can be the same last name if it does not have the same name. I'm not just checking if the name and last name mach. Can that be also done with counting?

Comment: The comment is confusing! Can you illustrate? Another thing, you also need to use some JavaScript to clear your forms. Use a unique identifier for a student, like a roll number or an email address, because names+surnames can be duplicate.

Comment: This form is in a custom plugin which uses custom table data and custom post type and it's shown in admin menu. Admin adds the students name and last name and email, and if he/she forgets that one student was already added or something like that I don't want to allow duplicate entries. So student with the same name and different email can be added, but if they have the same name and surname it's a duplicate entry. Maybe it would be easier just to check if the emails are different.

Comment: There you have it, emails are unique. It is perfectly valid for 2 people with the same names to exist but impossible with the same emails. Read my answer code, it uses the email as the unique ID to solve the duplicate entry issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can improve your code a lot. I'll treat the email address as the student's unique identification, since I can definitely have 2 students named 'John Doe'.

```
global $wpdb;
$tablename = $wpdb->prefix."students";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name = esc_attr($_POST['firstname']);
    $surname = esc_attr($_POST['lastname']);
    $email = sanitize_email($_POST['email']);

    if(!is_email($email)) {
        //Display invalid email error and exit
       echo '<div class="error"><p>Invalid e-mail!</p></div>';
       //return or exit
    }

    //Checking to see if the user email already exists
    $datum = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $tablename WHERE students_email = '".$email."'");

    //Print the $datum object to see how the count is stored in it.
    //I'm assuming the key is 'count'

    if($wpdb->num_rows > 0) {
        //Display duplicate entry error message and exit
        ?>
        <div class="wrap">
            <div class="error"><p>Student exsist!</p></div> <!-- wp class error for error notices --->
        </div>
        <?php
        //return or exit
    }

    //Now since the email is unique and valid, lets go ahead and enter it
    //assigning the new data to the table rows
    $newdata = array(
        'students_name'=>$name,
        'students_lastname'=>$surname,
        'students_email'=>$email,
        'students_date'=>current_time( 'mysql' ),
    );
    //inserting a record to the database
    $wpdb->insert(
        $tablename,
        $newdata
    );
    //displaying the success message when student is added
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="updated"><p>Student added!</p></div>
    </div>
<?php }
```

I have avoided a lot of unnecessary conditions and loops. Try this. Use some JavaScript to clear your form when a successful entry is made.

Update:
I have used `get_results` in accordance with the query you had posted. Now you have to use `$wpdb->num_rows` to count the number of results in the condition.

Source:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wpdb-mysql_num_rows

Comment: I think I need some conditions, because now it still adds the student if it has the same email.

Comment: Print the `$datum` object to see if it returns the proper data. Add an echo statement inside the `count` if to check if the condition is met.

Comment: It doesn't show anything, like it doesn't even check the if statement. I tried with var_dump and echo and nothing. Just adds the student.

Comment: Then you need to check the SQL query by running it directly on the DB.

Comment: I fixed it with different SQL query. I did it with `$datum = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $tablename WHERE students_email = $email", ARRAY_N);` and then the `if($datum > 0 )` and it works now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help. Please edit my answer and put the correct query there. May help someone in the future. By the way, there was a typo in my SQL query, I used `student_email` instead of `students_email`!

Comment: I edited your answer with the changed SQL query and I noticed the typo right away :D. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think you need to use `$wpdb->query` instead of `get_results` since you're checking an array against a 0, when you should actually be checking the count against the 0. Even though it works, it is wrong.

Comment: I was so focused on testing it if the users have the same email, I forgot to test it if it adds the new user, and it does not add it. I always get the error message. If I replace the get_results with query it adds the new user but it also adds it if it has the same email.

Comment: Lemme check the code once again. By the way, check my code... I have made a minor change to the query and the condition that checks it.

Comment: Still adding the user if it has the same email.

Comment: Because the comparison is wrong. You're comparing an object directly to 0. Remove the `ARRAY_N` param and var_dump the object to see how the count is returned. I'm updating my code.

Comment: I get bool(false) which is strange.

Comment: Right, so you just need to use a different function. Read the codex, `query` function returns boolean on succesful operation. I would suggest using `get_row` or `get_results` with `ARRAY_A` (associative array). Then count it in the condition. Use PHPMyAdmin to test your query.

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: Still adding the user with the same email. This is now driving me mental.

Comment: Changed the code to `$data = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $tablename WHERE students_email = '".$email."'"); ` and now I get the error but just can't add the new student.

Comment: I think I got it now.
`$data = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $tablename WHERE students_email = '".$email."'");if($wpdb->num_rows > 0){`

Comment: Apparently I don't got it. It works, then it doesn't. I don't know anymore.

Comment: Dude, print out the SQL query, run it directly on your DB. First with an existing email, then with a non existent one. If the query works, my code will work fine. Are you on Skype?

Comment: I think it works now with the code above. Just some testing glitches I guess. Thanks for all your help. Yes I'm on Skype.

Comment: That's great man. If you're stuck again, skype me, the id is rutwick.gangurde.